# How to check current date and move to next date in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, calendar

I am facing problem in my script.I want to check dates in bootstrap calandar. I want to check for today's date from the bootstrap calendar and need to check flight is available or not.If flight is available on that day further process will takes place.If not then pop up message will through flight not available.This is simple condition if i check with current date flight availability with bootstrap calendar.
But i want to check if today flight is not there then user able to go to next available date for searching flight and if available then further process.But i am not able to do that.
This is my code what i wrote:

```
    WebElement current_day=d.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[@class='day today']"));
    String today_day=current_day.getText();
    int today_day_in=Integer.parseInt(today_day);
    System.out.println("Today date:  "+today_day_in);
    for(int i=today_day_in;i<=31;i++)
    {
        if(all==i)
                {
                   mod.click(current_day);
                }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("erorr");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For current date you need to use this method

```
public static void getCurrentTime(){
     System.out.println("-----Current time of your time zone-----");
     LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
     System.out.println("Current time of the day: " + time);
 }
```

Comment: ok.But if i want to check for next available date and check flight is available or not and if not  then again search for next date . Like that if i want to do iterate how to do that?I am not getting.

Comment: based on that you have to wrote that logic for the available, can you just show the two screen shot and source where the flight is available and not available ..

Comment: sorry i am not able to upload screenshot .